# Cant install sams teach yourself in 24 hours sample database linux

Tags: mysql, linux

hey im using linux mysql and i keep on getting errors when i try to install the sample database that is used in the book. i have downloaded the sample file which is a .sql file. I have looked around and tried different ways to import it. The .sql file is located on the desktop.

here are some
Desktop$ mysql -u root -p airline < CanaryAirlineScript.sql
error is
bash: CanaryAirlineScript.sql: No such file or directory

USE airline;

SOURCE 
Failed to open file 'home/user/desktop/CanaryAirlineScript.sql', error: 2

Comment: You don't seem to be on the desktop with your command line. The command line typically starts out in the user directory, not the desktop.

Comment: Does `ls` show the file?

Comment: ls does show the file

Answer (score 0):

Your command `Desktop$ mysql -u root -p airline < CanaryAirlineScript.sql` means that you are importing a .sql file on your Desktop. The error message you are getting is because CanaryAirlineScript.sql is not located on your Desktop.

Comment: but the file is located on the desktop

Comment: Try to use the fully qualified path of the *.sql file. Such as `msyql -u root  -p airline < /home/user/desktop/CanaryAirlineScript.sql`